# Confused by different ways to create key:value dictionary pair for file renaming

Tags: snakemake

I am trying different ways to rename files and I am very confused why some of them are not working. Say I would like to copy file `in` to file `out` using a dictionary `{"out": "in"}`.

**Code NOT working #1:**

```
rename = {"out": "in"}

def mapFile(wildcards):
    print ('wc:',wildcards.rr)
    file = rename[wildcards.rr]
    return (file)

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{rr}", rr = list(rename.keys()))

rule rename:
    input:
        mapFile
    output:
        "{rr}"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"
```

error message:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
wc: out
wc: in
InputFunctionException in rule rename in file /Users/geo/Desktop/tmp/q.snakefile, line 12:
Error:
  KeyError: 'in'
Wildcards:
  rr=in
Traceback:
  File "/Users/geo/Desktop/tmp/q.snakefile", line 5, in mapFile (rule rename, line 19, /Users/geo/Desktop/tmp/q.snakefile)
```

and what confused me is that `rr` wildcard which is being passed to contains both `in` and `out`, but my dict key which I am expanding is only `out`...

**Code NOT working #2:**

```
rename = {"out": "in"}

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{rr}", rr = list(rename.keys()))

rule rename:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: rename[wildcards.rr]
    output:
        "{rr}"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"
```

error message:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
InputFunctionException in rule rename in file /Users/geo/Desktop/tmp/q.snakefile, line 12:
Error:
  KeyError: 'in'
Wildcards:
  rr=in
Traceback:
  File "/Users/geo/Desktop/tmp/q.snakefile", line 15, in <lambda> (rule rename, line 19, /Users/geo/Desktop/tmp/q.snakefile)
```

**Code WORKING #3:**

```
rename = {"out": "in"}

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{rr}", rr = list(rename.keys()))

rule rename:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: rename.get(f"{wildcards.rr}", "")
    output:
        "{rr}"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"
```

I do not understand what is going on. All three solutions should be identical, but only #3 works. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your rule rename can also produce the file `in`.  Since that file doesn't exist, snakemake tries to make it and runs into a key error in your input function for options 1 and 2.  You can see this clearer with the `--debug-dag` option and if you `touch in` all should work.  The third option "works" because when the requested file isn't in your dict, you return nothing.  Presumably if you ran that workflow it would fail to execute since the shell would be `cp in`.

More generally, you want your files to have unique prefixes or suffixes.  If you put the files into subidrectories:

```
def mapFile(wildcards):
    print ('wc:',wildcards.rr)
    file = 'inputs/' + rename[wildcards.rr]
    return file

rule rename:
    input:
        mapFile
    output:
        "outputs/{rr}"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"
```

All should work.  It's also good practice for organizing your outputs and when you have multiple rules it prevents ambiguous rules.